# Передача актуального state в redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть приложение на React + redux-toolkit. В бэкенде прописана логика авторизации и проверки jwt-токена. На фронте я делаю запрос на проверку пользователя. Если пришел корректный ответ, я этого пользователя диспатчу в стейт. Дальше я хочу пробросить этот стейт в дочерний компонент, что бы проверить, авторизован ли пользователь, и вывести нужную страницу, либо редирект на страницу логина. Суть проблемы в том, что в дочерний компонент пробрасывается initial state, в котором нет пользователя. Помогите решить проблему!

**App.jsx**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setUser } from "store/slices/userSlice";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp/SignUp";
import Main from "./components/Main/Main";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { checkAuth } from "api";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("email")) {
      checkAuth().then((data) => {
        dispatch(
          setUser({
            email: data.email,
            id: data.id,
            firstName: data.firstName,
            lastName: data.lastName,
            phone: data.phone,
            nickname: data.nickname,
            description: data.description,
            position: data.position,
            isAuth: true,
          })
        );
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main isAuth={state.user.isAuth} />} />
        <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Дочерний компомнент**

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeUser } from "store/slices/userSlice";
import Header from "components/Header/Header";
import { logout } from "api/index";

const Main = ({ isAuth }) => { //тут приходит false
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    logout();
    dispatch(removeUser());
  };

  return isAuth ? (
    <div>
      <Header handleLogout={handleLogout} />
      <h1>Welcome</h1>

      <button>Log out from</button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/signin" />
  );
};

export default Main;
```

**Redux Slice**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  email: null,
  id: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  phone: null,
  nickname: null,
  description: null,
  position: null,
  isAuth: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action) {
      state.email = action.payload.email;
      state.id = action.payload.id;
      state.firstName = action.payload.firstName;
      state.lastName = action.payload.lastName;
      state.phone = action.payload.phone;
      state.nickname = action.payload.nickname;
      state.description = action.payload.description;
      state.position = action.payload.position;
      state.isAuth = action.payload.isAuth;
    },
    removeUser(state) {
      state.email = null;
      state.token = null;
      state.id = null;
      state.firstName = null;
      state.lastName = null;
      state.phone = null;
      state.nickname = null;
      state.description = null;
      state.position = null;
      state.isAuth = false;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser, removeUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотел в комментарии написать, но в комментарии репутации не хватает, поэтому придется в ответе. :)
Вы как-то слишком усложнили и вам в принципе верно посоветовали упростить, используя useSelector в компоненте.
Еще правильнее будет сделать защищенные роуты. Оборачивая компоненты в компонент-обертку, который будет проверять логин и перенаправлять если пользователь незалогинен.

Вот так будет выглядеть защищенный роут (пример).

```
  <Route path='profile/orders/:id'
    element={
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <Order />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    } />
```

А вот так компонент ProtectedRoute.

```
import { useSelector } from "../../redux/store";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
 
export function ProtectedRoute(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const location = useLocation();
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((store) => store.auth);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  }

  return children;
}
```

Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не следует так прокидывать значения стейта в дочерние компоненты, которые находятся в рендер функциях роутов. Вы можете сделать все гораздо проще. Используйте `useSelector` в необходимом компоненте, в вашем случае это видимо `Main` и получите необходимое значение как только оно изменится в слайсе.